# No consigo entender bien RegExp

Tags: javascript

Intento obtener los parámetros de una URL cualquiera a través de un RegExp, pero me parece demasiado lioso lo que estoy leyendo y no me aclaro nada.

Ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
let u   = url.replace(new RegExp('^/'), '').split('/'),
let fc  = u.shift(), skin = u.shift(), path=u.join("/");
let fcb = fc.replace(new RegExp('?'),'').slit('?');
```

A partir de url, que es la URL completa con la que he de trabajar, se hace un RegExp para quitar de en medio todo salvo el nombre del archivo al que hacer referencia.

Yo intento dar con la forma de poder quitar también los parámetros que se pongan, es decir:

```
http://localhost:8080/social?param=cualquiera
```

Necesitaría obtener dicho param=cualquiera y separar 'social' de todo lo demás.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Has probado con `new URL(url).pathname` ? Creo que es una manera mucho más fácil para lo que quieres hacer. Luego puedes obtener los query strings usando `new URL(url).search` o `new URL(url).searchParams.get('param')` para obtener el valor de un parámetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener la parte final de la url, lo que serían los valores que siguea a ? lo más sencillo es usar location.search. En el ejemplo que pones al final de tu pregunta el resultado de **location.searh** sería **?param=cualquiera**. Ahora, con el método splice(1), le eliminas el carácter inicial (?).
Pero si lo que quieres es usar una expresión regular puedes hacer esto

```
reg = /\?(\w+)=(\w*)$/;
cad = "http://localhost:8080/social?param=cualquiera";
valores= cad.match(reg);
console.log(valores[1]);  //param
console.log(valores[2]);  //cualquiera
```

La expresión regular busca el carécter ? seguido de cualquiera carácter una o más veces seguido de un signo igual y después otra serie de caracteres justo al final de la cadena ($, indica final de la cadena).
Como ves ? se debe escapar \? porque  es un carácter usado en las expresiones regulares.
Las expresiones regulares son estupendas pero al principio son liosas. Debes tener muy claro lo que buscas y ser capaz de definirlo para poder crear el patrón.
**EDITO**
Si además necesitas el nombre que precede a la cadena de parámetros, o sea, entre el último / y el ? puedes hacer esto:

```
reg = /\/([^\/]+)\?(\w+)=(\w*)$/;
cad = "http://localhost:8080/social?param=cualquiera";
valores= cad.match(reg);
console.log(valores[1]);  //social
console.log(valores[2]);  //param
console.log(valores[3]);  //cualquiera
```

Ahora buscas lo que siga a una barra invertida y esté antes de un ?. Pero esos caracteres no pueden contener a la barra, por eso se precede ésta del ^.
Y ya puestos a rizar el rizo si además quieres sacar lo que precede a "social" pues añades otra agrupación a la expresión regular

```
reg = /(^.*)\/([^\/]+)\?(\w+)=(\w*)$/;
cad = "http://localhost:8080/social?param=cualquiera";
valores= cad.match(reg);
console.log(valores[1]);  //http://localhost:8080
console.log(valores[2]);  //social
console.log(valores[3]);  //param
console.log(valores[4]);  //cualquiera
```

Ahora se coge todo lo que hat entre el principio de la cadena (^) y la última barra / , seguido de lo que no sean barras y están seguidos del carácter ?, segido de lo que venga antes del signo = y finalmente lo que sigue a este signo y el final de la cadena.
Aparte de solucionar el caso concreto con esta respuesta pretendo explicar un poco como funcionan las expresiones regulares, siguiendo el enunciado de tu pregunta. Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: No era concretamente lo que buscaba, pero me diste la pista perfecta!
Muchas gracias! Edito con la respuesta que quería. Lo siento si no me expliqué correctamente en su momento.

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @EugeniBejan en los comentarios, la clase `URL` provee de varios metodos para obtener información de la url, una posibilidad es usar `searchParams`:

```js
const url = new URL('http://example.com/path/index.html?parametro1=un_valor&parametro2=otro_valor');

const parametros = {}

url.searchParams.forEach((e,i)=>parametros[i] = e);

console.log(parametros)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir separar la url de los parametros simple y llanamente tuve que utilizar esta expresión:

`let cad = fc.match(/\?/m);`

Así me da un Array de dos objetos con lo que hay delante y detrás de la ?